# Why aren't all square roots irrational?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, radicals, rationality-testing

The more known proof of square root of $2$ is by contradiction when we assume it can be expressed as an irreducible fraction and later finding that it isn't irreducible, but... if we assume the same conditions for example: square root of $9$ we find that it isn't irreducible either. So, what's the trouble here?

Comment: because square root of 4 is 2 or -2 and the fundamental algebraic theorem tells us that $x^2 -4 =0$ has at most 2 solution and we find them.

Comment: How can that explain my doubt? Am sorry I can't get it.

Comment: @ZackNi I don't really see how your comment is relevant to this question.

Comment: The proof of the irrationality of $\surd 2$ hinges on the *prime factorisation* of $2$ having *odd* indices (aka $2^{\bf 1}$).  The prime factorisation of integers such as $4$ or $9$ do not have odd indices; they are $2^{\bf 2}, 3^{\bf 2}$ respectively.

Comment: When you have $9a^2 = b^2$ and you conclude $9|b^2$ you don't have to conclude 9|b because you can have just 3|b.  Which will not lead to us requiring 9 divides a.  There is no contradiction.

Comment: I like to explain it in terms of operations. Square root is by definition the inverse operation of squaring, i.e. multiplying a number by itself. We know that the result of multiplication of two natural numbers is always a natural number too. Thus, we necessarily have a set of 'perfect squares', i.e. natural numbers which are the results of squaring some other natural number. So, when we take the square root of a perfect square we have to obtain a natural number too. This explanation might not be rigorous, but it's how I understand all of this myself

Comment: Have you tried to actually follow the same proof in the case of $9$? (I'm not being patronizing here, just wondering.)

Comment: @YuriyS: I think that's correct: in short the reason not all square roots are irrational is that rational numbers can be squared, and the result of doing that is of course a number with a rational square root. The only quibble to make it rigorous is that since the square function isn't injective on the rationals, it's not actually true that the square root of $x^2$ is necessarily $x$. But we can probably satisfy ourselves that $x$ is rational if and only if $-x$ is! Alternatively we can talk about positive integers only so that the square function is injective.

Answer (score 45):

*Let's look at the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational:*

To show $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, we argue by contradiction. Suppose $\sqrt{2}={p\over q}$, where $p, q$ are natural numbers. Without loss of generality, ${p\over q}$ is in lowest terms. So ${p^2\over q^2}=2$, and so $p^2=2q^2$. $\color{red}{\mbox{This means that}}$ $2$ divides $p$, that is, $p=2k$. So $2q^2=4k^2$, and $q^2=2k^2$. $\color{red}{\mbox{Again, this means}}$ that $2$ divides $q$. But then $p$ and $q$ have a common factor, contradiction.

---

**Where this breaks down for $\sqrt{4}$**: Look at the red phrases. They depend on the following fact: $$\mbox{If $2$ divides $ab$, then either $2$ divides $a$ or $2$ divides $b$}.$$ This fact requires *proof*, and relies on the fact that $2$ is prime. $4$, by contrast, is not prime, and indeed the fact fails for $4$: $4$ divides $2\cdot 2$, but $4$ does not divide $2$.

**How it generalizes**: It's a good exercise to show that the usual argument *does* work for any number $n$ such that some prime $p$ divides $n$ an odd number of times - that is, $p^{2i+1}$ divides $n$ but $p^{2i+2}$ doesn't, for some $i$. For example, the following numbers all have this property:

- $12$ ($p=3, i=0$)
- $27$ ($p=3, i=1$)
- $24$ ($p=2, i=1$ or $p=3, i=0$)

etc. Any such number has an irrational square root. By contrast, if every prime dividing $n$ divides $n$ an *even* number of times, then $\sqrt{n}$ is rational (exercise!). So this is a complete characterization.

Comment: [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) says that if $p$ is prime and $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ and $p\mid ab$, then either $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$, or more generally if $n,a,b\in\mathbb Z$ and $\gcd(n,a)=1$ and $n\mid ab$, then $n\mid b$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\sqrt{9}=\frac{a}{b}$$

where $\gcd(a,b)=1$.
$$\sqrt{9}b=a$$
Squaring both sides,
$$9b^2=a^2$$

We know that $a$ must be a multiple of $3$ (notice I am saying $a$ is a multiple of $3$ rather than $9$ and compare it with the proof for irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$.)

So $a=3k$ and hence $b=k$. $k$ takes value $1$ in this case.

Comment: "$k$ takes value $1$ in this case":  of course, that is *one* value that it can take, but it doesn't *necessarily* do so.  (Also, of course we could as well have $b = -k$.)

Comment: Let me impose one more condition, $a$,$b>0$.

Comment: Ah, I read too quickly, and missed the (crucial) bit that $\gcd(a, b) = 1$.  Of course then (with your added positivity condition) you are right that $k = 1$.

Answer (score 5):

The standard proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational is of course as follows: Assume for contradiction there exist $a, b$ positive whole numbers that share no factors (besides $1$) and $a / b = \sqrt{2}$. Then $a^2 = 2 b^{2}$. Now the observation here is that $2 b^{2}$ is divisible by $2$, *a prime number*, so $a$ must also be divisible by $2$.

Now, if instead we considered $9$, then we'd be looking at $a^2 = 9b^2$. We cannot conclude from here that $a$ is divisible by $9$, so we are dead in our tracks.

Answer (score 2):

See this proof that 
if $n$ is not a perfect square
then $\sqrt{n}$
is irrational:

[Follow-up Question: Proof of Irrationality of $\sqrt{3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391411/follow-up-question-proof-of-irrationality-of-sqrt3/1391466#1391466)

The proof starts by saying that
if $n$ is not a perfect square
then there is a $k$ such that
$k^2 < n < (k+1)^2$.
The proof breaks down if
$k^2 = n$.

Answer (score 0):

Because the proof relies on that the root isn’t an integer

$\gcd(p,q)=1, \frac{p}{q}=sqrt(9)\implies p^2=9*q^2 \implies 9|p^2$.  Normally we would say now that this means $9|p$ as we would with $2$, but that neglects the case where $q=1$, i.e. $9=p^2$, but in this case, that isn’t true.

Comment: This isn't really true - nowhere in the standard proof do we assume that $q\not=1$. Instead, what's going on is that we use the fact that $2$ is prime - which means that if $2$ divides a product $a\cdot b$, then $2$ divides one of the factors. In particular, if $2$ divides $a^2$ then $2$ divides $a$. This *fails* for nonprimes in general - e.g. $9$ divides $6^2$ but does not divide $6$.

Comment: Right, but showing that 2 is prime usually is done by showing that its irreducible, i.e. doesn't have any integer factors (aside from 1 and itself), which would imply a that its square root isn't an integer.